# Error in JAVA SDK installation - eclipse-java-indigo

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to install JAVA Indigo 32bit to Windows 10 PC.
I downloaded `eclipse-java-indigo-SR2-win32` and ran `eclipse.exe` but following error occur.

> "A Java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK) must
>   be available in order to run Eclipse. No Java virtual machine was
>   found after searching the following locations:
>   C:\Users\Mike\Downloads\eclipse-java-indio-SR2-win32\eclipse\jre\bin\javaw.exe
>   javaw.exe in your current PATH"

Can anybody give me any advice?

Comment: You are going to need a 32 bit Java JRE/JDK and since Indigo is ancient (8 years old now) it will have to a fairly old Java (Java 8 at the very latest I would think).

Comment: I want to install latest version of Java SDK 32bit. Does the latest version support 32bit?

Comment: Eclipse Indigio will **not** run with the current Java 11, recent versions of Java contain changes that Indigo will not understand. You must use the latest Eclipse to run with Java 11 and it is only 64 bit.

Comment: Any reason why you want to have eclipse indigo ?

Comment: Existing environment is Eclipse Indigo, so I need to stick to Eclipse Indigo and should find compatible JRE.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install jdk first in order to run eclipse

Comment: Which version of jdk should be installed for java eclipse indio?